# Failed to update 'database_name' database is read only in Always on Availability group

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

Background:

I have a Always On Availability Group Setup with 4 Nodes(DB1,DB2,DB3,DB4). I am using File Share witness hosted on some other server. All the nodes on AG are set to failover automatically. And as readable secondary option set to 'yes'.

Issue:

For instance, lets consider DB1 as primary node on both AG and WSFC. Now,whenever I stop the MSSQL service on DB1, DB2 or the other 2 becomes primary on AG. However, DB1 stays as primary host on the WSFC. The main problem here is whenever my application tries to connect to the DB, I get an error as "Failed to update 'Dbname' database is read only". But when I manually change the node of WSFC to the now Primary AG DB my application starts working. Can someone please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever my application tries to connect to the DB, I get an error as "Failed to update 'Dbname' database is read only"

Your app needs to connect to the AG through the [AG Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/availability-group-listener-overview?view=sql-server-ver15), which will only be active on the node hosting the primary database replica.

If your app is connecting to the listener you need to troubleshoot the connection.  Verify that DNS resolution is returning all the IP addresses, and that only the IP address hosting the primary replica has the requested SQL Server port open.

Comment: Yes. I am connecting using the AG listner.

Comment: Then why is your application connecting to the wrong node?

Comment: How can I check that? Any specific setting I need to make to avoid this?

Comment: nslookup and test-netconnection from the app server to the database server.

Comment: Nslookup to the AG listner takes me to the Virtual IP configured for the cluster. TNC is successful to the AGlistner and the individual DB sever IPs.

Comment: This is a single-subnet cluster with a single IP for the AG Listener?  By "Virtial IP configured for the cluster" do you mean the IP of the AG Listener or the IP of the cluster?  Sounds like your app might be configured to connect to the Cluster IP not the AG Listener IP.

Comment: Nslookup should return the individual server IPs or the Cluster VIP?

Comment: Never the Cluster VIP.  It should return the IPs of the AG Listener.  If it's a single-subnet cluster the AG Listener typically has a single floating IP.

Comment: In my case I have single IP. I dont recall having a separate IPs for AG and Cluster.

Comment: Then you may not have set up an AG Listener.  You might have multiple AGs (or other apps) on the cluster, so they can't all just be active on the node hosting the cluster core resource.

Comment: Ok I got it. Can the Cluster VIP be a non existent IP? Does it require to be an assigned static one. The AG listner needs to be static I understand.